# Duplicate routes need to fallback to next matching route when no Action is found

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

I have a situation where I need to override methods in an old HttpHandler API in an ASP.NET WebForms application. I'm using WebAPI as the base for the new API and it's been working great except I need the routing to fallback when an action is not found in the new API. This is not true currently, instead I get a "404: Not Found" whenever the WebAPI controller does not have a matching Action.

**My routing for the new API is as follows:**

```
var apiroute = routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "API Default",
    "api/{language}-{country}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**The old Httphandler APIs register their routes as follows (order is after WebAPI route):**

```
var route = new Route("api/{language}-{country}/Person/{command}", this);
RouteTable.Routes.Add(route);
```

I want /api/en-US/Person/List to match the first route if theres a PersonController with a List action but to fallback to the old api if there is not.

***Question:** Is it possible to add a filter to the first route to only match if the Action is indeed available on the controller? How else could I accomplish this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You may also want to investigate [attribute based routing](http://attributerouting.net/) this may be a cleaner solution only the actions you annotate with the routing attributes will be matched to the route and that may help you achieve what you want.

**Or**

Although there may be better ways than this, it is possible if you implement a custom `IRouteConstraint` e.g. [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs).

A highly rough and ready approach you could improve upon is below:

```
public class IfActionExistsConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var actionName = values["Action"] as string;

        if (actionName == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var controllerName = values["Controller"] as string;
        var controllerTypeResolver = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerTypeResolver();
        var controllerTypes = controllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetAssembliesResolver());
        var controllerType = controllerTypes.SingleOrDefault(ct => ct.Name == string.Format("{0}Controller", controllerName));

        if(controllerType == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return controllerType.GetMethod(actionName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) != null;
    }
}
```

**Registration:**

```
var apiroute = routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{language}-{country}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { IfActionExistsConstraint = new IfActionExistsConstraint() }
);
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more optimized way to achieve the same thing but this may well be the best way. Add some in-memory caching of the types and names it could potentially not have such a huge impact on performance.

I have also considered setting up each route that is to be overridden specifically and I have not yet decided which approach would be the best trade-off between ease of use and performance.

Comment: @magix agree this is a large overhead, although it can be optimised as you pointed out via an in memory cache (which is what the frameworks ControllerSelectors do). I have updated my answer to include attribute based routing this can allow a finner granularity for defining routes and may also help.